# JMeter ActiveMQ Topic Test Plan

Tags: jmeter, activemq-classic

I am trying setup an ActiveMQ topic test plan in apache-jmeter-5.3 by following the steps mentioned in [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/jmeter-jms-topic-test-plan) guide. However, when I run the test plan in Jmeter, I get the following exception.

```
Response message:javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:  org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
```

I have copied the activemq-all-5.15.13.jar in the lib directory of JMeter but still getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `activemq-all-5.15.13.jar` indeed contains `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`? If so, then it seems that JMeter isn't actually picking that jar file up in its classpath.

Comment: Yes, `ActiveMQ-all-5.15.13.jar` contains `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`

Answer (score 0):

You need to **restart JMeter** to pick the `activemq-all-5.15.13.jar` from the [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).

---

Alternatively you can add the library at [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level, in this case restart is not required:

[image]

More information:

- Official [Building a JMS Point-to-Point Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html) article
- Unofficial [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) which fills some gaps

Comment: Indeed restarting the JMeter after adding `activemq-all-5.15.13.jar`  is an important step.  However, In my case, I was placing the `activemq-all-5.15.13.jar` in `JMeterHome/lib` directory. The issue fixed, after moving the `activemq-all-5.15.13.jar` to `JMeterHome/lib/ext` directory